# writing efficient scala function for matching nicknames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 hive tables `A` and `B` that contains information about some users. Table `A` is huge (hundreds of millions of rows) and table `B` is regular size in the range of 1 million rows. I need to match first names using nickname matching between them: `A` and `B`.

`Table A`:

```
pid      fn         ln
001    Bill    Lattner
002    Tom     Jenkins
003    Dan     Forsyth
004    Mark    Simmons
```

`Table B`:

```
uid      fnam     lnam
103   William  Lattner
105    Thomas  Jenkins
208    Daniel     Lark
```

I also have a file with nickname pairs, `nicknames.dat`:

```
Bill     William
Tom      Thomas
Dan      Daniel
Matt     Matthew
```

I am trying to find out how to write an efficient scala function to perform the nickname matching task to be used in Spark. I have some experience writing scala code. What I am not sure about is how to write an efficient scala function to run on Spark. For example, I can write the following function in scala:

```
def nicknameMatching(fn1: String, fn2: String, pairs: Vector[(String, String)]): Boolean =
  pairs.contains((fn1, fn2)) || pairs.contains((fn2, fn1))
```

Where `pairs` is constructed with `nicknames.dat`.

I know that there are tricks to make the program run faster in Spark on a cluster such as caching, broadcasting, ect. What is the best way to write this function (as well as some other setup) such that it runs most efficiently in Spark on an actual cluster?

Comment: maybe you can use join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your desired output is, but my thoughts are as follows:

- The contents `nicknames.dat` is presumably much smaller than either A or B and therefore easily fits in memory.
- If so, iterating over table B and looking up corresponding full name doesn't require Spark and the overhead of Spark isn't worth it for that operation.
- You presumably then want to join the result of the last step (call it B') to table A. B' has as many rows as B (or fewer if you're only interested in people with nicknames), so you could broadcast it and have a copy on each worker.

A little code for the first two steps:

```
case class Bentry(uid: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String)

val nicknames: Map[String, String] = (your nicknames, keys as first names, values last name)

val tableB: Seq[Bentry] = (table B's entries)

val bWithNicknames: Seq[(Bentry, String)] = tableB.map(nicknames.getOrElse(_.firstName, ""))
```

Now, convert `bWithNicknames` to a data frame `bDF` and assume you have A as a dataframe `aDF`. Then (assuming appropriately named columns and that you want a left join):

```
val result = aDF.join(broadcast(bDF), Seq("firstName", "lastName), "left")
```